# How to write test case using Appium in C#?

Tags: c#, android, appium, selendroid

I want to use [Appium](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_0) to make automated testing for my Android app. I downloaded the [Appium for Windows](http://appium.io/) and could run my app on device from within [appium.exe](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_166). Now I want to write test cases in C# which make use of `selendroid` integrated in [Appium](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_0). I googled a lot but couldn't find any example demonstrating the same. I found one [project](https://github.com/appium/appium-dot-exe) on github but it's giving a lot of compiler errors. Could anybody guide me about how to write test cases using Appium in C#? If you have any resources, please provide me the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can go with installing Visual Studio 2012 or visual express for web. Use NUnit framework to write the test cases and execute them as a class library project in that.

Comment: it will be appreciated if you could provide resources/links to achieve what you have just mentioned.

Comment: There are no such links to help on this , i downloaded visual studio , created an class library project then used the NUnit structure to set up the capabilities and started writing the test cases. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Appium.WebDriver/  <-- this link will explain how to add the Appium Webdriver references to your class library project. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ and  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/ packages are needed to initialize the webdriver to connect to the Appium server.

Comment: I guess this link will be very much useful in adding the dll files and also configure the NUnit framework to write your test cases and build your project accordingly. http://blog.wedoqa.com/2012/02/how-to-setup-selenium-webdriver-with-visual-studio-and-nunit/

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver . This link will be helpful for you with a basic start.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a class library project and create a new class e.g "Class1". Add the packages as provided in the links above. Try the below code

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
    using System.Threading;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.MultiTouch;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Interfaces;
    using System.Drawing;

    namespace ClassLibrary2
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class Class1
        {
            public AppiumDriver driver;
            public DesiredCapabilities capabilities; 

            public Class1()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Appium server");
                capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "Android");
                capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Windows");
                capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version ,"4.1.2");
                capabilities.SetCapability("Device", "Android");

                //Application path and configurations

               driver = new AppiumDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            }


        [Test]
        public void login()
        {

            driver.FindElement(By.Name("Country")).Click();
            //Your further code as per the application.



        }
```

Then Build a solution for your project and run it in NUnit.